# Java - cases in which instanceOf is not considered bad practice

Tags: java, oop, equals, instanceof

We learned in OOP class that using instanceOf is considered bad practice and should be avoided.
I would like to know, in general, what are the exceptions to this rule of thumb?

For example, what about overriding `Object.equals` method? This method gets an Object, so it has to be checked before the comparison.. Is it bad practice in this case as well?

Thanks

Comment: Before asking *what are the exceptions to this rule...*, one should ask *Why the rule? Why is it considered bad practices, and in what circumstances?*... Methinks.

Comment: IMO `instanceof` is never "good". It's basically always icky to some degree, but sometimes necessary. So the question should be "when is there no good way to avoid `instanceof`" or maybe "when is it the lesser evil".

Comment: "This method gets an Object, so it has to be checked before the comparison.". It can't really be bad practice because it **has** to be checked. But in most code you don't need to check the object's type, because you're either working with correct types or suitable supertypes. You can encounter loss of typing (and therefore may need `instanceof`) when working with reflection for example.